# Base64 - python vs. java values greater than 63

Tags: java, python, base64

I am trying to convert some code of python to java. And now stuck with the python base64 encoder with values greater than 63.

*python:*

```
s = chr(59) + chr(234)
print(base64.b64encode(s))
 >> O+o=
```

*java*

```
char[] chars = {59, 234};
String data = new String(chars);
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(data.getBytes());
System.out.println(new String(encoded));
 >> O8Oq
```

Anyone any idea?

Comment: You should explicitly define the character set on the Java side, to match the default ASCII encoding used on the Python side.

Comment: Thank you, know I get the right output with getBytes("ISO-8859-1").

Answer (score 1):

Note that your snippet in Python already deals with bytes whereas the Java version starts with Unicode characters and then transforms them to bytes by calling `data.getBytes()`.

You can achieve the same result in Python by encoding to UTF-8 first:

```
>>> (unichr(59) + unichr(234)).encode('utf-8').encode('base64')
'O8Oq\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final java code:

```
char[] chars = {59, 234};
String data = new String(chars);
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
System.out.println(new String(encoded));
 >> O+o=
```

Thank you all for help. :)